# как остановить выполнение bash скрипта из python 3

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, subprocess

Есть скрипт следующего содержания:

```
#!/bin/sh
$1
exit
```

Запускаю его в новом процессе

```
subprocess.run(["bash", "script", "command"])
```

Насколько я знаю, функция run() ждет окончания выполнения процесса, но как мне программно получить доступ к запущенному процессу и остановить его выполнение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [группу процессов](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group), чтобы разрешить отправку сигнала всем процессам в группах. Для этого вы должны прикрепить [идентификатор сеанса](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsid.html) к родительскому процессу порожденных / дочерних процессов, который является оболочкой в ​​вашем случае. Это сделает его лидером группы процессов. Итак, теперь, когда сигнал отправляется руководителю группы процессов, он передается всем дочерним процессам этой группы.

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

# The os.setsid() передается в аргументе preexec_fn поэтому
# он запускается после fork() и перед exec() для запуска оболочки.
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                       shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid) 

os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)  # Отправка сигнала всем процессам группы
```

Comment: а причем тут группа процессов?

Comment: группа процессов обозначает коллекцию из одного или нескольких процессов . Помимо прочего, группа процессов используется для управления распределением сигнала ; когда сигнал направляется в группу процессов, сигнал доставляется каждому процессу, который является членом группы.

Comment: просто кильнуть дочерний баш и всё... обычно достаточно.